# Send array to the API

Tags: angular, typescript

The API (written in C#, ASP.NET Core) receive 3 fields: title, content and an array of categories (integers):

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult CreatePublication(string title, string content, IEnumerable<int> categoryIds)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

The problem is the API always receive zero elements in the categoryIds array.

The client in Angular4:

```
let ccategoryIds = new Array<number>()
ccategoryIds.push(2)
ccategoryIds.push(5)
ccategoryIds.push(7)

let requestOptions = {
  params: new HttpParams()
    .set('title', 'The title')
    .append('content', 'The content')
    .append('categoryIds', ccategoryIds.toString()),
  withCredentials: true
}

this.http
  .get('http://localhost:53203/api/publications/createPublication', requestOptions)
  .subscribe(data => {
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
     alert('Error')
  })
```

**Update**

If I use **JSON.stringify(ccategoryIds)** instead of **ccategoryIds.toString()**, I receive zero elements in the API too.

[image]

It is not a problem of the backend. In Postman it works:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I can't see how you have written the API handler, but I thin you are using `.toString()` where you should be using `JSON.stringify()`:

```
let ccategoryIds = new Array<number>()
ccategoryIds.push(2)
ccategoryIds.push(5)
ccategoryIds.push(7)

let requestOptions = {
  params: new HttpParams()
    .set('title', 'The title')
    .append('content', 'The content')
    .append('categoryIds', JSON.stringify(ccategoryId)),
  withCredentials: true
}

this.http
  .get('http://localhost:53203/api/publications/createPublication', requestOptions)
  .subscribe(data => {
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
     alert('Error')
  })
```

Comment: @JohnDoe this seems like a problem on the C# side.  Can we see your code there?